# RPI2 + WLAN and no cable LAN

Tags: wifi

I've a small problem with RPI2 WLAN after rebooting and at now no working answer from forum.

EDIMAX is installed using this tutorial: https://www.datenreise.de/raspberry-pi-wlan-einrichten-edimax/.
With plugged WLAN stick and wired LAN cable I can login with PUTTY and have adjust the file

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

with this content:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
#wireless-power off
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.2.119
netmask 255.255.255.0
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-scan-ssid 1
wpa-ssid "<my SSID>"
wpa-psk "<my PSK>"
#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.200
netmast 255.255.255.0

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1[/code]
```

Always I like the static IP.

Problem:
If LAN cable is plugged and WLAN stick is plugged I can access both IPs and connect both. If I remove the LAN cable the connection the WLAN connection is OK.
If I reboot the RPI2 without LAN cable and only WLAN stick I have no access. Then if I connect the LAN cable there is
no WLAN connection possible till I logged in over cable LAN. After this I can also log in with WLAN.

Question:
Is there a possibility to connect with WLAN after frech reboot and no LAN cable plugged? BUT! I don't
like to put cable LAN into trash all the time. If necessary I like to connect the cable LAN and log in with this.

How can I solve this?

Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer by myself:

this is my /etc/network/interfaces entry:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#iface eth0 inet static
#address 192.168.2.116
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.2.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.2.119
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-scan-ssid 1
wpa-ssid "<my_ssid>"
wpa-psk "my_psk>"
```

I comment out the eth0 stuff.

Now reboot the RPI without lan cable by removing the power cord and plug it again. RPi boot with static IP and you can access it by PUTTY.
If you plug in the lan cable AFTER booting again, no lan is accessable.
If you have plugged WLAN stick AND lan cable before booting you will have both IPs after boot process and access both if it's up.

Mike.F.